# how can we connect to azure sql database from .net web application which uses entity framework developed in .net framework 4.6.2 by azure MSI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, .net-4.6.2

i tried with Managed service identity changes in configuration but it is only available in .net framework 4.7.2 but i need to get it work in 4.6.2 with entity framework

Comment: I don't think that is supported. It requires features in the framework classes which don't exist in 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Managed service identity changes in configuration is only available in .Net framework 4.7.2. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39012#issuecomment-532512884